# Algolia changes createdAt date to object with $date property

Tags: algolia

We have a MongoDB database with a leads collection. Inside this collection every object has a `createdAt` property. When exporting the collection to a JSON file every object has a `createdAt` property with a value like `2019-09-01T19:49:05.413Z`.

When uploading the file to Algolia the property changed to a date object and looks like this:

```
"createdAt": {
   "$date": "2019-09-01T19:49:05.413Z"
}
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: are you planning to do any sorting, filtering based on the createddate? if so you will need to have it as a unix timestamp in algolia index

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fkcf6dommJ2 in your case this is mongo behaviour. possibility is you could write a script in your preferred language to query from db and format the data. then index in algolia using the same script